# MySQL PID Errors

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, centos6, timezone

While attempting to change the MySQL server timezone to CDT to match the Centos sytem time, something has messed up. I edited the `my.conf` in `/etc/` in vim logged in to SSH as root, and saved it. On `service mysql restart`, I got the following error:

```
root@server [~]# service mysql restart
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/server.find-minecraft-servers.com.pid).
root@server [~]#
```

This keeps going round in circles. I've tried locating that pid file - it's not apparant. I've tried `service mysql status`, it mentions a lock file in /var/lock/subsys/mysql - I delete this, nothing changes. Please help me out.

The contents of my.conf is:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=1
```

(I reset it after the timezone change messed it up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If mysqld is running (check your process table), you should probably stop it via a kill command (dont use kill -9 as that will do an un-graceful stop of the service).

When mysqld is no longer present in the process table, start the service normally.

Comment: Note that this may result in some database corruption, but generally MySQL should be able to recover just fine.

Comment: Agreed, but you probably have no choice at this point if the lockfile is gone